# Can't mount network drive properly over Wi-Fi

Tags: usb, mount, lubuntu, fstab, network-drive

I am trying to mount a network drive on Lubuntu 16.4 Raspberry Pi edition.
I want to clarify, that *I can mount it using the* `mount` *command*.
The issue is with mounting it on boot. I've already modified `/etc/fstab`.
It works properly when over Ethernet.

**However, when only the USB Wireless Adapter is installed the network drive fails to mount (error code -101)**.

I have a suspicion that this is caused by not having initialized the Wi-Fi Adapter before Lubuntu mounts the drives from fstab.

What Can I do?

Comment: apparently there's a "_netdev" option, which waits for network before mounting, you can add `_netdev` to fstab options and try

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a *supported* release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm

Comment: FYI:  The oldest *supported* release of Lubuntu is currently Lubuntu 20.04 LTS - https://lubuntu.me/lubuntu-21-10-end-of-life-and-current-support-statuses/

Comment: @guiverc
I am using a Raspberry Pi 2. Is there even a newer release that works with it?

Comment: thank you for the tip, @Cagri!

Comment: Note: I will repost this on unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: Raspberry Pi 2/3/4's were used to test 22.04; Lubuntu doesn't provide either *armhf* or *arm64* images, but you install the server system & use `desktopify` to add the desktop you like to use.

Comment: OP has reposted question at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/716005/cant-mount-network-drive-properly-over-wi-fi-cifs-error-101/716006#716006

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I found a very good solution using automount with `systemd`. It is explained here : https://ppfeufer.de/linux-on-demand-nfs-and-samba-cifs-connections-with-systemd-automount/

1. Install the required packages:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install samba cifs-utils nfs-common
   ```
2. Create a mount point:

   ```
   sudo mkdir -p /mnt/network/myshare
   ```
3. Create a credentials file:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/samba/credentials
   ```

   with the following lines inside:

   ```
   username=your_username
   password=your_password
   ```
4. Then run:

   ```
   sudo chmod 600 /etc/samba/credentials
   ```
5. Create the `systemd` unit files:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/mnt-network-myshare.mount
   ```

   Example: CIFS

   ```
   [Unit]
   Description = My Share mount
   Requires = dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service
   After = network-online.target
   Wants = network-online.target

   [Mount]
   What = //example.server/myshare
   Where = /mnt/network/myshare
   Options = credentials=/etc/samba/credentials,vers=3.1.1,uid=your_username,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0655,dir_mode=0655,noperm
   Type = cifs
   TimeoutSec = 30

   [Install]
   WantedBy = multi-user.target
   ```

   Example: NFS

   ```
   [Unit]
   Description = My Share mount
   Requires = dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service
   After = network-online.target
   Wants = network-online.target

   [Mount]
   What = example.server:/myshare
   Where = /mnt/network/myshare
   Options = defaults
   Type = nfs
   TimeoutSec = 30

   [Install]
   WantedBy = multi-user.target
   ```
6. Create an automount file:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/mnt-network-myshare.automount
   ```

   with the following content:

   ```
   [Unit]
   Description = Automount for My Share
   ConditionPathExists = /mnt/network/myshare

   [Automount]
   Where = /mnt/network/myshare
   TimeoutIdleSec = 0

   [Install]
   WantedBy = multi-user.target
   ```
7. Test that it worked:

   ```
   sudo systemctl daemon-reload
   sudo systemctl start mnt-network-myshare.mount
   sudo systemctl status mnt-network-myshare.mount
   ```

   The output should be like this:

   ```
   mnt-network-myshare.mount - My Share mount
      Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mnt-network-myshare.moun; static; vendor preset: enabled)
      Active: active (running) since Fri 2022-04-29 10:10:03 CEST; 1min 1s ago
       Where: /mnt/network/myshare
        What: //example.server/myshare
     Process: 13005 ExecMount=/bin/mount //example.server/myshare /mnt/network/myshare -t cifs -o vers=3.1.1,credentials=/home/your_username/.mount-credentials/myshare,iocharset=utf8,rw,x-systemd.automount,uid=1000 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
       Tasks: 0 (limit: 4915)
      CGroup: /system.slice/mnt-smb-sambashare.mount

   Apr 29 10:10:03 your_pc systemd[1]: Mounting My Share mount...
   Apr 29 10:10:03 your_pc systemd[1]: Mounted My Share mount.
   ```
8. You can test the automount too:

   ```
   sudo systemctl start mnt-network-myshare.automount
   sudo systemctl status mnt-network-myshare.automount
   ```
9. Enable your automount files to start at boot:

   ```
   sudo systemctl enable mnt-network-myshare.automount
   ```